# is there an equivalent of data-frame in OCaml?

Tags: pandas, ocaml

I have been on the R side for some years. I don't do any hardcore statistics, but rather use R as a sophisticated 'csv-files' manipulater. nevertheless, i do need to process a huge amout of data, in a distributed way.

I found that R is not fast enough for my application anymore and I am now investigating other languages.

the first choice is Python-pandas, which is faster. Also, I read that Ocaml could be 10x faster than python, which sounds very attractive to me.

However, i found that the standard libraries of Ocaml seems to be quite low-level. I cannot find any high-level containers like R's data frame.

How do you guys represent data frames in Ocaml? do you use a list of tuples? can anyone share a bit knowledge here?

thanks!

Comment: When considering performance, also consider that sizable parts of NumPy/Pandas are written in C not Python.

Answer (score 2):

I had to google for data frames in R, not being familiar with R, but it seems like you're looking for records, or perhaps a list of records. Or as you suggest, maybe a list of tuples would have similar properties to R data frames if you add some functions to access the data in the tuples more easily. But I think records would be closer as you can refer to the name of a field in the record.

See the chapter on [Records](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/records.html) in Real World OCaml.

Comment: Presumably he also wants an easy way to read/write them. I personally use [sexplib](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/sexplib/index.html) for that.

Answer (score 2):

I am actually working on a dataframe class right now for OCaml. Hopefully I will have it finished in a few weeks. My progress so far is on GitHub. (Note: The current version on github does not have function 100%).

https://github.com/PamExx/TimeSeries/blob/master/TimeSeries.ml

Comment: I am assuming this project has not reached completion yet?

Comment: If it is the case that this package is no longer being developed, would you be able to provide an idea of an alternative?

Comment: I have not worked on this package in a while. I have recently been using some code I have written to interface OCaml with R. This works by passing OCaml float/int lists to R as c() vectors, passing commands to R (usually just a command to run an R script) and retrieving the results back to OCaml. I do this via a Lwt unix process. There is also an Ocaml-R library out there that could also be an option but I have not used it. I can share my code if you would be interested.

Comment: Thanks Thomas but no - I was looking for an OCaml pure solution, for the very reason that I have a complex set of algorithms already written in R, and I find it to be much too slow, especially at data manipulation. Thus I wish to cut R out of the loop completely.

Comment: What kind of data & data structures are you working with? I have also written some code for processing large amounts of time series data. It has enabled me to work with GBs of data that I was unable to work with in R due to memory & speed limitations. It may be useful for you b/c you can process all of the data 100% in OCaml.

Comment: That could be extremely useful. My data algorithms are fairly complex but the data structures tend to be fairly simple tabular series - indeed financial time series. I work with minute and tick data in equity, foreign exchange, commodity and bond markets. Typically I have about 200-300 thousand ticks per series, with up to 1000 series being worked with at any one time (maximum). Currently it's about 20meg per series so I am struggling with 32 gig node: soon upgrading to 64 gig. I would be *very* interested to know about timeseries structures that I could use in OCaml....

Comment: .... Please note that I am new to OCaml, so please do not treat me like an expert (yet), but I am a looking forward to my adventure in this language.

Comment: Send me an e-mail (see my profile) with some more detail about the structure of your data and I will post some code that might be useful to Github.

Comment: The link is broken. Could you please fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in Thomas answer, such a rich data structure would be provided by a specialized library. You can start with either an array of records or a record of arrays. If your rows are not floating-point numbers only, a record of arrays might be slightly preferable. But perhaps it is more important for cache locality whether you work across rows (then array of records) or across columns (then record of arrays). Beware that you might want to base computations on low-level libraries such as [LACAML](https://bitbucket.org/mmottl/lacaml) or [Stream Processing with OCaml](http://www.algo-prog.info/spoc/web/index.php) -- you should study their APIs to get inspiration how to implement your high-level data structure. It would be nice if someone provided the actual high-level library! You can also try to work with both OCaml and R using [OCaml-R](http://home.gna.org/ocaml-r/).